# django custom queryset filtering, for a specific thing first, then everything else

Tags: django, sorting, django-queryset

I was wondering if it was possible to do a custom queryset filter

something like

Steve, apples

Mary, apples

Dan, apple

Steve, oranges

Mike, oranges

Mary, oranges

Mike, pears

So that the main ordering is by fruit name
But if there are a few ppl with the same fruit, a specific user (in this case Steve) will always be first.

And also distinct, so that only the first of each bunch of fruits shows up.

Steve, apples

Steve, oranges

Mike, pears

I've tried a custom Manager, which seemed to overwrite my normal Model.objects.functions

I tried a raw sql and extra, but it's returning lists and not querysets (I believe), things that don't have queryset 
methods, which are called in later code.

Comment: Why would you need that to be the first result? Why not just make 2 queries, one to find that and then anther to get the other results?

Comment: Sorry - I misworded, corrected original post

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify which user could be on the first record, because database can only sort the whole records by certain criteria. You could at most do:

`Model.objects.all().order_by('fruit', 'name')`

This can give you a queryset that sorts first by fruit, then within each fruit sort by name, but in one queryset you can never put someone's name on the top.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is doable in SQL. Problem is that I need to return a queryset object. Is there anyway to convert a rawqueryset to a normal queryset, or to use SQL in filtering a queryset